# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` while attempting to activate 'AuthenticateController'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting this error in Login Controller.

**System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[UsersAuth.IdentityAuth.UserApplication]' while attempting to activate 'UsersAuth.Controllers.AuthenticateController'.**

here is Authenticate Controller constructor:

```
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<UserApplication> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AuthenticateController(UserManager<UserApplication> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
```

and here is ConfigureServices in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     })
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
         options.SaveToken = true;
         options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
         {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
             ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]))
         };
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't configure Dependency Injection for `UserApplication`. There are different ways to do that, for example

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserApplication>(options =>
   options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

or, if you want more granular control,

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt => {
    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    ...
})
.AddSignInManager()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you it's working now :))

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, you may want to mark it as such